# Spring MVC xml to java configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, configuration

This is my first attempt to convert xml based spring mvc application configuration to java based configuration.

Below is my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Below is my initializer class..

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new 
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.register(WebConfig.class);      
    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));                    
    context.setServletContext(container);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", 
new DispatcherServlet(context));
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("*");
}
}
```

Below is my spring configuration xml.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" abstract="false" scope="singleton">
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    <property name="expectedType" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/jndiname" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>        

<bean id="authenticationService" class="com.mypackage.service.AuthenticationService">
    <property name="ldapURI" value="${ldap.ldapURI}" />
    <property name="contextFactory" value="${ldap.contextFactory}" />
    <property name="secutiryAuthentication" value="${ldap.secutiryAuthentication}" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:ldap.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="encryptionService" class="com.mypackage.service.TrippleDESCipherService"/>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Below is my java class to replace the spring configuration xml.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.mbfs.accounting.bpay")
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:db-
config.properties","classpath:ldap.properties" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSource() {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSource = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    dataSource.setCache(true);
    dataSource.setLookupOnStartup(true);
    dataSource.setProxyInterface(javax.sql.DataSource.class);
    dataSource.setExpectedType(javax.sql.DataSource.class);
    dataSource.setJndiName(env.getProperty("jndi.jndiName"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSource) {
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) dataSource;
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);        
    jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
    return jdbcTemplate;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationService authenticationService() {

    AuthenticationService authenticationService = new AuthenticationService();
    authenticationService.setLdapURI(env.getProperty("ldap.ldapURI"));
    authenticationService.setContextFactory(env.getProperty("ldap.contextFactory"));
    authenticationService.setSecutiryAuthentication(env.getProperty("ldap.secutiryAuthentication"));
    return authenticationService;
}

@Bean(name="encryptionService")
public TrippleDESCipherService trippleDESCipherService() throws DESCipherException {

    TrippleDESCipherService encryptionService = new TrippleDESCipherService();
    return encryptionService;

}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-
INF/resources/");

}
}
```

I am able to start the application without any errors. After starting the application, I get 404 error saying my login file not found. I'm not sure what did I miss with java based configuration. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You get a 404 response when the resource you requested was not found: what was your request? It looks like you forgot to add a configuration for authentication (spring security?)

Comment: Shouldn't you servlet url be `servlet.addMapping("/*");` ?

Comment: @willerr, I'm using ldap authentication. I added the authenticationService bean for that. the request is.. localhost:9081/<context>/login

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna, I've tried different mappings.. but no luck. Its giving me 404 resource not found.